# Ubuntu Package Distribution Requirements Question

Tags: apt, software-center

I'm interested in publishing software to Ubuntu (I believe this is correct, I know you can just publish to Launchpad too). I'd like people to be able to install it with

```
apt-get install <program>
```

and then Ideally have it added to be auto run on startup.
Right now, I just have a repository set up and its they run a script to install it. Kinda clunky.

My question - If my software has a dependency on a server that I run (for the sake of this question, assume you run the program and give it a text file, and the text file shows up on a server (mine) somewhere they can access. Whatever, you get the idea.

Is this something that can be published or do things need to be entirely self contained? (e.g. I could theoretically take the server down, killing the app).

Comment: You mention 'debian', but I'm not sure how you mean it.  Do you mean publish .deb packages? or packages for use with debian?   This site supports Ubuntu and official flavors only, and debian is neither.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to sort of publishing software. I'd like to be able to publish some software so users can install it on Ubuntu with 'apt-get install <mysoftware>'
I spent some time looking into it, and there's a lot of content to digest. To be quite honest, I'm not 100% sure how to get the above accomplished as well as the approval process. Thank you for any help btw!

Comment: I don't have time now to look, but this may help a little. https://launchpad.net/+tour/ppa or https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA?action=show&redirect=PPA , maybe also http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/  (*I uploaded my first (& so far only) deb package to a ppa last december and had no issues; but i only modified an existing package & uploaded it for testing purposes. Thus I already had templates for everything...*)   PPA's are not audited (they are 3rd party) so post-installation scripts could do a lot in theory; but the idea of it screams problems & I not touch it (*why risk your rep.*)